# Jsoup and arraylist android

Tags: java, android, xml, jsoup

I successfully extract tag from xml content using jsoup for one element.

```
class Post {

private String a;
private String b;


public void setA (String a){
       this.a = a;

}


public void setB(String b){
       this.b =b;

}

public String getA(){

return a;
}

public String getB(){

return b;
}

}
```

by using arraylist

```
public ArrayList<Post> PostList = new ArrayList<Post>();
```

how can i store the values of a b under different index using jsoup. i extract single tag

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(soap_xml_content);

Element element1 = doc.select("a");
Element element2 = doc.select("b");

String value_a = element1.text();
String value_b = element2.text();
```

---

**Xml:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
    <soap:Body> 
        <wsListeCompt> 
            <comptes> 
                <a>pen drive</a> 
                <b>jsoup</b> 
            </comptes> 
            <comptes> 
                <a>pen drive</a> 
                <b>jsoup</b> 
            </comptes> 
            <comptes> 
                <a>pen drive</a> 
                <b>jsoup</b> 
            </comptes> 
        </wsListeCompt> 
    </soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<wsListeCompt>


<comptes>
<a>pen drive</a>
<b>jsoup</b>
</comptes>

<comptes>
<a>pen drive</a>
<b>jsoup</b>
</comptes>

<comptes>
<a>pen drive</a>
<b>jsoup</b>
</comptes>

</wsListeCompt>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code wont compile since `select()` will return an `Elements` object, not an `Element`.

```
Elements aElements = doc.select("a"); // Select all a-elements
Elements bElements = doc.select("b"); // Select all b-elements
```

Now you iterate over all elements found and store them as you want:

```
for( Element element : aElements )
{
    postList.add(element.text());
}
```

*(Do the same for b-elements)*

---

**Example:**

```
    Elements aElements = doc.select("a");
    Elements bElements = doc.select("b");


    // This 'if-else' block is optional
    if( aElements.size() != bElements.size() )
    {
        // Error handling - if required
    }
    else
    {
        // Iterate over all elements
        for( int i = 0; i < aElements.size(); i++ )
        {
            Post p = new Post();    // Create a Post

            p.setA(aElements.get(i).text());    // Set A Value
            p.setB(bElements.get(i).text());    // Set B Value

            PostList.add(p);    // Add the Post to List
        }
    }
```

Comment: what about the setter getter. if i say getB() i need to get all b element and if i want only 1 element of b will this still work ?

Comment: i want every a b to be in the same index

Comment: that is for each comptes add a in setA(A) and add b in setB(B)

Comment: If i understand aright, you want to deserialize your xml into a java object? `Elements` is a List so if you need only one element, call `aElements.get(0)` (or another index).

Comment: Btw. if you want to deserialize xml, take a look at [Simple XML Framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: i want to store the each element in an array list<<Post>> and acess it using getter setter

Comment: i see, you can access each element stored in elements by its index using `aElements.get(index)`. Iterate over all elements found and use that index for getting *a* and *b*. now make an instance of `Post` with the selected values and store them in your list.

Comment: can you provide me with an example please